# How to check URL health synchronized without timeout error?

Tags: vbscript, msxml

I am trying to write a RSS reader in vbscript. To make sure that the RSS url exists or is healthy I use the following code:

```
function testUrl(url)
    testUrl=0
    Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    on error resume next
    o.open "GET", url, False
    o.send
    if o.Status = 200 then testUrl = 1
    on error goto 0
    set o=nothing
end function
```

I have set XMLHTTP async to false because I need to know the real response of a url however if the target server response takes a long time I will also get script timeout error on my own side because I am checking the url health Synchronized . How should I check the url health sychronized (even async) but get rid of possible timeout errors in my own script?

Error details:

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113'
>
> Script timed out
>
> /update.asp
>
> The maximum amount of time for a script to execute was exceeded. You
> can change this limit by specifying a new value for the property
> Server.ScriptTimeout or by changing the value in the IIS
> administration tools.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Is it an HTTP 408 status or a vbs error? Do you ever receive a response back from the server? Perhaps for testing, do `If o.Status = 200 then testUrl = 1 Else Msgbox o.Status`

Comment: I don't know how to simulate that error. I tested the vbscript code in IIS in asp classic and the error was about `Script timed out`. It is not a message from the target URL but from my own IIS engine.@K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: The target status may become 200 after a long time but causes timeout error on my own side. @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: added the error details in question @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: That is due to the ASP page timing out while waiting for a response, try adjusting the `Server.ScriptTimeout` in your ASP page or adjust it through the IIS Manager.

Comment: You'll want to adjust the XHR timeout so it is less than the ASP page so you can trap it and return an error etc.